# Displaying a message based on category id in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I'm trying to show a different message based on whether there is a category id or not.

Here is my code

```
    $product = Product::find($id);

    if($product->category_id == null)
    {
        return view('product-result', [
            'message' => 'There is no categories attached to this product';
        ]);
    }else{
        return view('product-result', [
            'message' => 'There is a category attached to this product';
        ]);
    }
```

The issue I'm having is that even if the product does have a category id I'm still getting the first message where it tells me that there is no categories

Comment: I think you code should be work well with this condition. Make sure those product have category.

Comment: try using `isset($product->category_id) && !empty($product->category_id)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the entity of the product.

```
$product = Product::find($id);

if($product === null)
{
    return view('product-result', [
        'message' => 'There is no categories attached to this product';
    ]);
}

return view('product-result', [
            'message' => 'There is a category attached to this product';
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing your code like this

```
$product = Product::find($id);

if(isset($product->category_id) && !empty($product->category_id))
{
    return view('product-result')->with('nocategoryMsg','There is no categories attached to this product .');
}else{
    return view('product-result')->with('hascategoryMsg','There is a category attached to this product .');
}
```

Access it in view using

```
@if(!empty($nocategoryMsg))
  <div class="alert alert-danger"> {{ $nocategoryMsg }}</div>
@endif

@if(!empty($hascategoryMsg))
  <div class="alert alert-danger"> {{ $hascategoryMsg }}</div>
@endif
```

Comment: your `==null` only checks if it is null, isset() checks null as well as if the property of the object exists(if category_id in product exists) and !empty will check for if value is not ' '